# Flutter Firebase incorrect document path

Tags: flutter, dart

Im having a problem creating a new document in a sub collection.
I keep getting

> a document path must point to a valid document.

Put simply i have this structure

users/id1/templates

Im trying to create a "template" for a user using this:

the path variable is:

> users/pweo0H4toHgvF3CEj8xXQ4M1kcC2/templates/

```
  Future<void> setData({
    @required String path,
    @required Map<String, dynamic> data,
    bool mergeBool = false,
  }) async {
    try {
      final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path);
      print('$path: $data');
      await reference.set(data);
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you fix it?

Comment: From memory i had to reference the collection after doc ie. FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(path).colllection, but i would have to check to be sure

Comment: Sorry, never mind... My problem was because I passed an empty string as id by mistake...